# Elasticsearch not running with search guard

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, search-guard

- ES v2.4.1
- SG-SSL v2.4.1.16
- SG v2.4.1.6
- CentOS 7.2

Im able to run Elasticsearch with Search-Guard-SSL. I generated the certs/keys via the example script from Search Guard. Here is the info on the kirk client cert that I generated

```
> openssl x509 -noout -subject -in kirk-signed.pem -text
subject= /C=US/L=Raleigh/O=client/OU=client/CN=kirk
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 3 (0x3)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: DC=com, DC=example, O=Example Com Inc., OU=Example Com Inc. Signing CA, CN=Example Com Inc. Signing CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct  6 14:47:01 2016 GMT
            Not After : Oct  6 14:47:01 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=US, L=Raleigh, O=client, OU=client, CN=kirk
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

If I understand correctly, I need to have the following line in my elasticsearch.yml file, correct?

```
# Enable SSL via Search Guard SSL plugin
# Enable HTTPS
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: true
searchguard.ssl.http.keystore_filepath: node-0-keystore.jks
searchguard.ssl.http.keystore_password: pw
searchguard.ssl.http.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
searchguard.ssl.http.truststore_password: pw

# Enable SSL between ES nodes
searchguard.ssl.transport.keystore_filepath: node-0-keystore.jks
searchguard.ssl.transport.keystore_password: pw
searchguard.ssl.transport.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
searchguard.ssl.transport.truststore_password: pw
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false

# for Search Guard
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
  - "cn=kirk, ou=client, o=client, l=Raleigh, c=US"

searchguard.cert.oid: '1.2.3.4.5.5'
```

But when I run sgadmin.sh, it just times out

```
> /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-2/tools/sgadmin.sh -cd /etc/elasticsearch/ -ks kirk-keystore.jks -ts truststore.jks -nhnv -kspass pw -tspass pw
Will connect to localhost:9300 ... done
Contacting elasticsearch cluster 'elasticsearch' and wait for YELLOW clusterstate ...
ERR: Timed out while waiting for a green or yellow cluster state.
```

And I see these in elasticsearch.log

```
[2016-10-06 15:17:41,354][DEBUG][com.floragunn.searchguard.action.configupdate.TransportConfigUpdateAction] [Arize] Node started, try to initialize it. Wait for at least yellow cluster state....
[2016-10-06 15:17:41,523][DEBUG][com.floragunn.searchguard.configuration.SearchGuardIndexSearcherWrapperModule] FLS/DLS not enabled
[2016-10-06 15:17:41,667][DEBUG][com.floragunn.searchguard.configuration.SearchGuardIndexSearcherWrapperModule] FLS/DLS not enabled
[2016-10-06 15:17:41,698][DEBUG][com.floragunn.searchguard.configuration.SearchGuardIndexSearcherWrapperModule] FLS/DLS not enabled
[2016-10-06 15:17:41,728][DEBUG][com.floragunn.searchguard.configuration.SearchGuardIndexSearcherWrapperModule] FLS/DLS not enabled
[2016-10-06 15:17:42,099][DEBUG][com.floragunn.searchguard.configuration.SearchGuardIndexSearcherWrapperModule] FLS/DLS not enabled
[2016-10-06 15:18:11,746][WARN ][com.floragunn.searchguard.action.configupdate.TransportConfigUpdateAction] [Arize] index 'searchguard' not healthy yet, we try again ... (Reason: timeout)
[2016-10-06 15:18:44,747][WARN ][com.floragunn.searchguard.action.configupdate.TransportConfigUpdateAction] [Arize] index 'searchguard' not healthy yet, we try again ... (Reason: timeout)
[2016-10-06 15:19:17,749][WARN ][com.floragunn.searchguard.action.configupdate.TransportConfigUpdateAction] [Arize] index 'searchguard' not healthy yet, we try again ... (Reason: timeout)
```

What am I missing?